# What's the difference between web service (API) implementation with REST and routing?

Tags: 8

what are the real differences between these two methods of creating a webservice :

1. Routing + Controller (https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/custom-restful-api-drupal-8)
2. REST plugin (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources)

advantages/disadvantages of both?

I think we can create a restfull API with one as with the other, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

actually to create a wbesrvice endpoitns  in Drupal 8 we need to activate  one of or both of this 2 modules :

1. **JSON:API module (best one)**:

after the activation of this module you can
       access to all Drupal entities (user , node , taxonomy ) throw a dynamic endpoints that have this structure **http://{host}/json_api/{entity_type}/{bundle}?Parameters**, with the ability to fitter the result + built in pagination + sorting ex of endpoints :

- **/jsonapi/node/article** : get a json contains all node article.
- **/jsonapi/node/article,sort=-created** : get a json contains all node article and order them with e created field in DESC
  order.article.
- **/jsonapi/taxojomy_term/article** : get a json contains all taxnomy term category.

> understand the Drupal entity type first will be better :
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrSjwe8bh7I
>
> then use the  JSON:api using this videos :
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--ZL3EAhnwc&list=PLZOQ_ZMpYrZsyO-3IstImK1okrpfAjuMZ

2. **RESTful Web Services**

   - Exposing Views using the RESTful Web Services module( Do you need an easy configuration from backoffice to set up and endpoint ?) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMvNwRVJSEQ.
   - Creating a Custom REST Resources to expose data that can’t be exposed by the previous solution - when to use  this solution when none of the previous solution can expose this data (Does **JSON:API**  and **View exposing** can't expose this type of data ?)

note : the methos in this url https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/custom-restful-api-drupal-8 never use it because we get out of the context of drupal, and you waon't be able to use a hiddne power of Rest module ex  :l by default any custom rest endpoint will display i if rest ui (https://www.drupal.org/project/restui) module installed .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I already know the existence of jsonapi for entities ^^. In fact, I never liked the default renderings like jsonapi nor views :p I always prefer to develop in custom :/ (it probably has disadvantages). But, so what I retained, the advantage of the REST Plugin is that we could benefit from restui quite simply.

Comment: also the custom rest is a Drupal plugin  , and Drupal plugin is just a solution for a recursive problem (design pattern) in this case problem : exposing an endpoint, so you gonna find a lot of methods inherited from the ResourceBase class in this case , that help you to solve problems that occurs a lot in Drupal  , for exmaple you can easily set the authentication by installing a third module ex: https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth ( aid mobarak :) ).

Comment: unfortunately I never had the opportunity to call on RessourceBase (I don't even know its usefulness nor its existence :( ) with Custom Rest so I hope to delve more on the design pattern and plugin of drupal ;) Allah i barek fik

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can implement API REST using both methods, (Routing+Controller) or (Plugins).

**(Routing+Controller)**

- Its an initial approach and it is not recommended to use it at these
  times for API REST.

**(Plugins), Its recommended to use it, why?**

- Define a standard (for all developers) for creating Web
  services/endpoint in Drupal 8+.
- Its in `core` to this purpose! Its like as a superior version of the
  classic (Routing+Controller) implementation with much others REST
  improvements.
- It has integration with other modules and features like `basic_auth`,
  `jsonapi`, `restui`, etc (not the other method, Routing+Controller).

Among other things, basically I think is for that.

> In other words, to not reinvent the wheel, use **Plugins**.

Comment: Precisely, why look far if the classic method could answer all these points.  

- standard method for all developers (because now there are developers following the other and others the other)

- we can adapt the construction of the API according to RESTFull. Manage methods, header and rendering format etc ...

- I agree for the restui ^^

In short, REST Plugin is the new fashionable method: p to create APIs. Better to use it to be up to date ;)



Thank you for your reply